# show that $f(z)+f(z^2)+\cdots + f(z^n)+\cdots$ converges locally uniformly to an analytic function in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk and $f(0)=0$, show that $$f(z)+f(z^2)+\cdots+ f(z^n)+\cdots$$ converges locally uniformly to an analytic function in the unit disk.

I am thinking to apply Weierstrass $M$ test for convergence or since all the $f(z^n)$ are analytic in the unit disk, so each of them can be expressed as the taylor series. Then rewriting the series again might work. But I am not sure.
Any suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean $f(0)=0$? If $f(z)=0$ then there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 6):

$f(z) = z \cdot g(z)$ with $g(z)$ holomorphic on the unit disk so $g$ bounded of compact subsets. We conclude that for any $0< r < 1$  there exists an $M = M_r$ so that
$$|f(z)| \le M \cdot |z|$$
for all $z$ in $\bar D(0, r)$ the closed disk of radius $r$.

Therefore, on $\bar D(0, r)$ we have 
$$|f(z^n)| \le K \cdot |z^n| \le M \cdot r^n$$

We can apply the Weierstrass M test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to conclude  that the series of holomorphic functions
$$\sum_n f(z^n) $$

converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D(0,1)$ to a holomorphic function.

Obs: the series expansion at $0$ of this function is obtained by summing the series expansions on $f(z^n)$, the coefficient of $z^m$  stabilizes after summing $m$ terms.

Comment: Does $g(z)$ being holomorphic in unit disk imply $g(z)$ is bounded there? Why not $f(z)$ is bounded which is also analytic in the unit disk.

Comment: @Santosh: Oh, it could be only defined  on the open unit disk, like $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-z}$ so $g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: How do I argue that the locally uniformly convergent limit is an analytic function on the unit disk

Comment: Use Morera's theorem and the fact that local uniform convergence lets you interchange the limit and the integral on a closed contour.

Comment: @Santosh: Cauchy's integral formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula holds for the limit too.