# Compact convergence $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f(z^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, holomorphic-functions

Let $f \colon \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic with $f(0) = 0$. Ist there a way to prove the compact convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f(z^n)$$
**without** using the Taylor series and then applying some theorem for double serieses?

Comment: What is $\Bbb E$?

Comment: @Clayton the open unit disc as usual

Comment: I see it written as $\Bbb D$... I can't say I've ever seen the usage of $\Bbb E$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer No, this is not the nice case for lemma of Schwarz :-(

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022157/show-that-fzfz2-cdots-fzn-cdots-converges-locally-uniformly-to-an,

Comment: @arney: Thanks.  My question is rather irrelevant, based on wrong thinking.  The question I linked to appears to have it covered.